# Angular2 Error self.parentView.context.. is undefined

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm trying to go on my angular 2 webapp but I get this error on each page : 
[image]

I haven't changed anything in the app, and it works on computers of people of my team.

Is it caused by these warnings when `npm install` ?

> npm WARN deprecated angular2-google-maps@0.17.0: Please use the new
>   package name
>   @agm/core - Details here: htt://... npm WARN prefer global
>   node-gyp@3.6.2 should be installed with -g
>
> > node-sass@4.5.3 install C:...\node_modules\node-sass
> >     node scripts/install.js
>
> Downloading binary from
>   https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.5
>   .3/win32-x64-48_binding.node Download complete Binary saved to
>   C:...\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-48\bindi
>   ng.node Caching binary to
>   C:\Users\toto\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\node-sass\4.5.3\win3
>   2-x64-48_binding.node
>
> > tslerp@1.0.5 postinstall C:...\node_modules\tslerp
> >     typings install
>
> typings WARN enoent Path
>   "C:...\node_modules\tslerp\typings.json" is missing
>
> `-- (No dependencies)
>
> > node-sass@4.5.3 postinstall C:\Users\aviale\Documents\dev\workspace\PlaceDesFa
> >     milles\PlaceDesFamilles\PlaceDesFamillesFront\node_modules\node-sass
> >     node scripts/build.js
>
> Binary found at
>   C:\Users\aviale\Documents\dev\workspace\PlaceDesFamilles\PlaceDe
>   sFamilles\PlaceDesFamillesFront\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-48\bindi
>   ng.node Testing binary Binary is fine
>
> > ng2-google-recaptcha@1.1.0 postinstall C:...\node_modules\ng2-google
> >     -recaptcha
> >     typings install
>
> typings WARN enoent Path
>   "C:...\node_modules\ng2-google-recaptcha\typings.json" is missing
>
> `-- (No dependencies)
>
> place-des-familles-front@0.0.0
>   C:...
>   +-- @angular/cli@1.0.0-beta.31 | +-- @ngtools/json-schema@1.0.3 | +-- @ngtools/webpack@1.2.9 | | +-- enhanced-resolve@3.1.0 | | +--
>   loader-utils@0.2.17 | | | +-- big.js@3.1.3 | | | +-- emojis-list@2.1.0
>   | | | `-- json5@0.5.1 | |`-- magic-string@0.19.1 | |   `-- vlq@0.2.2
>   | +-- async@2.4.1 | +-- autoprefixer@6.7.7 | | +-- browserslist@1.7.7
>   | | |`-- electron-to-chromium@1.3.14 | | +-- caniuse-db@1.0.30000686
>   | | +-- normalize-range@0.1.2 | | +-- num2fraction@1.2.2 | | +--
>   postcss@5.2.17 | | | +-- js-base64@2.1.9 | | | `--
>   supports-color@3.2.3 | |`-- postcss-value-parser@3.3.0 | +--
>   chalk@1.1.3 | | +-- ansi-styles@2.2.1 | | +--
>   escape-string-regexp@1.0.5 | | +-- has-ansi@2.0.0 | | | `--
>   ansi-regex@2.1.1 | | +-- strip-ansi@3.0.1 | |`-- supports-color@2.0.0
>   | +-- common-tags@1.4.0 | | `-- babel-runtime@6.23.0 | |`--
>   regenerator-runtime@0.10.5 | +-- css-loader@0.26.4 | | +--
>   loader-utils@1.1.0 | | +-- lodash.camelcase@4.3.0 | | +--
>   object-assign@4.1.1 | | +-- postcss-modules-extract-imports@1.1.0 | |
>   | `-- postcss@6.0.2 | | |`-- supports-color@3.2.3 | | +--
>   postcss-modules-local-by-default@1.2.0 | | | `-- postcss@6.0.2 | | |`
>   -- supports-color@3.2.3 | | +-- postcss-modules-scope@1.1.0 | | | `--
>   postcss@6.0.2 | | |`-- supports-color@3.2.3 | | +--
>   postcss-modules-values@1.3.0 | | | +-- icss-replace-symbols@1.1.0 | |
>   | `-- postcss@6.0.2 | | |`-- supports-color@3.2.3 | | `--
>   source-list-map@0.1.8 | +-- cssnano@3.10.0 | | +-- decamelize@1.2.0 |
>   | +-- defined@1.0.0 | | +-- has@1.0.1 | | |`-- function-bind@1.1.0 |
>   | +-- postcss-calc@5.3.1 | | | +-- postcss-message-helpers@2.0.0 | | |
>   `-- reduce-css-calc@1.3.0 | | |   +-- balanced-match@0.4.2 | | |   +--
>   math-expression-evaluator@1.2.17 | | |`--
>   reduce-function-call@1.0.2 | | |     `-- balanced-match@0.4.2 | | +--
>   postcss-colormin@2.2.2 | | |`-- colormin@1.1.2 | | |   +--
>   color@0.11.4 | | |   | +-- color-convert@1.9.0 | | |   | | `--
>   color-name@1.1.2 | | |   |`-- color-string@0.3.0 | | |   `--
>   css-color-names@0.0.4 | | +-- postcss-convert-values@2.6.1 | | +--
>   postcss-discard-comments@2.0.4 | | +--
>   postcss-discard-duplicates@2.1.0 | | +-- postcss-discard-empty@2.1.0 |
>   | +-- postcss-discard-overridden@0.1.1 | | +--
>   postcss-discard-unused@2.2.3 | | |`-- uniqs@2.0.0 | | +--
>   postcss-filter-plugins@2.0.2 | | | `-- uniqid@4.1.1 | | |`--
>   macaddress@0.2.8 | | +-- postcss-merge-idents@2.1.7 | | +--
>   postcss-merge-longhand@2.0.2 | | +-- postcss-merge-rules@2.1.2 | | |
>   +-- caniuse-api@1.6.1 | | | | +-- lodash.memoize@4.1.2 | | | | `-- lodash.uniq@4.5.0 | | | +-- postcss-selector-parser@2.2.3 | | | | +--
>   flatten@1.0.2 | | | | +-- indexes-of@1.0.1 | | | |`-- uniq@1.0.1 | |
>   | `-- vendors@1.0.1 | | +-- postcss-minify-font-values@1.0.5 | | +--
>   postcss-minify-gradients@1.0.5 | | +-- postcss-minify-params@1.2.2 | |
>   |`-- alphanum-sort@1.0.2 | | +-- postcss-minify-selectors@2.1.1 | |
>   +-- postcss-normalize-charset@1.1.1 | | +-- postcss-normalize-url@3.0.8 | | | +-- is-absolute-url@2.1.0 | | | `--
>   normalize-url@1.9.1 | | |   +-- prepend-http@1.0.4 | | |`--
>   query-string@4.3.4 | | |     `-- strict-uri-encode@1.1.0 | | +--
>   postcss-ordered-values@2.2.3 | | +-- postcss-reduce-idents@2.4.0 | |
>   +-- postcss-reduce-initial@1.0.1 | | +-- postcss-reduce-transforms@1.0.4 | | +-- postcss-svgo@2.1.6 | | | +--
>   is-svg@2.1.0 | | | |`-- html-comment-regex@1.1.1 | | | `-- svgo@0.7.2
>   | | |   +-- coa@1.0.3 | | |   |`-- q@1.5.0 | | |   +-- csso@2.3.2 | |
>   |   | `-- clap@1.2.0 | | |`-- whet.extend@0.9.9 | | +--
>   postcss-unique-selectors@2.0.2 | | `-- postcss-zindex@2.2.0 | +--
>   debug@2.6.8 | |`-- ms@2.0.0 | +-- denodeify@1.2.1 | +-- diff@3.2.0 |
>   +-- ember-cli-normalize-entity-name@1.0.0 | +-- ember-cli-string-utils@1.1.0 | +-- extract-text-webpack-plugin@2.1.2 |
>   | +-- loader-utils@1.1.0 | | +-- schema-utils@0.3.0 | | | `--
>   ajv@5.1.5 | |`-- webpack-sources@1.0.1 | |   `--
>   source-list-map@2.0.0 | +-- file-loader@0.10.1 | |`--
>   loader-utils@1.1.0 | +-- findup@0.1.5 | | +-- colors@0.6.2 | | `--
>   commander@2.1.0 | +-- fs-extra@2.1.2 | |`-- jsonfile@2.4.0 | +--
>   get-caller-file@1.0.2 | +-- glob@7.1.2 | | +-- fs.realpath@1.0.0 | |
>   +-- inflight@1.0.6 | | | `-- wrappy@1.0.2 | | +-- inherits@2.0.3 | | +-- once@1.4.0 | |`-- path-is-absolute@1.0.1 | +-- html-webpack-plugin@2.28.0 | | +-- html-minifier@3.5.2 | | | +--
>   camel-case@3.0.0 | | | | +-- no-case@2.3.1 | | | | | `--
>   lower-case@1.1.4 | | | |`-- upper-case@1.1.3 | | | +--
>   clean-css@4.1.4 | | | +-- commander@2.9.0 | | | | `--
>   graceful-readlink@1.0.1 | | | +-- he@1.1.1 | | | +-- ncname@1.0.0 | |
>   | |`-- xml-char-classes@1.0.0 | | | +-- param-case@2.1.1 | | | +--
>   relateurl@0.2.7 | | | `-- uglify-js@3.0.16 | | |`-- commander@2.9.0
>   | | +-- pretty-error@2.1.0 | | | +-- renderkid@2.0.1 | | | | +--
>   css-select@1.2.0 | | | | | +-- boolbase@1.0.0 | | | | | +--
>   css-what@2.1.0 | | | | | +-- domutils@1.5.1 | | | | | | `--
>   dom-serializer@0.1.0 | | | | | |   +-- domelementtype@1.1.3 | | | | |
>   |`-- entities@1.1.1 | | | | | `-- nth-check@1.0.1 | | | | +--
>   dom-converter@0.1.4 | | | | |`-- utila@0.3.3 | | | | +--
>   htmlparser2@3.3.0 | | | | | +-- domelementtype@1.3.0 | | | | | +--
>   domhandler@2.1.0 | | | | | +-- domutils@1.1.6 | | | | | `--
>   readable-stream@1.0.34 | | | | |   +-- isarray@0.0.1 | | | | |`--
>   string_decoder@0.10.31 | | | | `-- utila@0.3.3 | | |`-- utila@0.4.0 |
>   | `-- toposort@1.0.3 | +-- inflection@1.12.0 | +-- inquirer@3.1.0 | |
>   +-- ansi-escapes@2.0.0 | | +-- cli-cursor@2.1.0 | | |`-- restore-
>   ...
>   UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/platform-browser@4.2.2 | +--
>   @types/fullcalendar@2.7.43 | `-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY zone.js@^0.8.4
>   +-- codelyzer@2.0.1 | +-- app-root-path@2.0.1 | +-- css-selector-tokenizer@0.7.0 | | +-- cssesc@0.1.0 | | +--
>   fastparse@1.1.1 | |`-- regexpu-core@1.0.0 | |   +-- regenerate@1.3.2
>   | |   +-- regjsgen@0.2.0 | |   `-- regjsparser@0.1.5 | |`--
>   jsesc@0.5.0 | +-- cssauron@1.4.0 | +-- semver-dsl@1.0.1 | | `--
>   semver@5.3.0 | +-- source-map@0.5.6 |`-- sprintf-js@1.0.3
>   +-- core-js@2.4.1
>   +-- fullcalendar@3.4.0
>   +-- jasmine-core@2.5.2
>   +-- jasmine-spec-reporter@2.5.0 | `-- colors@1.1.2
>   +-- jquery@3.2.1
>   +-- karma@1.2.0 | +-- bluebird@3.5.0 | +-- body-parser@1.17.2 | | +-- bytes@2.4.0 | | +-- content-type@1.0.2 | | +-- debug@2.6.7 | | +--
>   depd@1.1.0 | | +-- http-errors@1.6.1 | | +-- iconv-lite@0.4.15 | | +--
>   on-finished@2.3.0 | | |`-- ee-first@1.1.1 | | +-- qs@6.4.0 | | +--
>   raw-body@2.2.0 | | | +-- bytes@2.4.0 | | | +-- iconv-lite@0.4.15 | | |
>   `-- unpipe@1.0.0 | |`-- type-is@1.6.15 | |   `-- media-typer@0.3.0 |
>   +-- chokidar@1.7.0 | | +-- anymatch@1.3.0 | | +-- async-each@1.0.1 | | +-- glob-parent@2.0.0 | | +-- is-binary-path@1.0.1 | | |`-- binary-extensions@1.8.0 | | +-- is-glob@2.0.1 | | | `--
>   is-extglob@1.0.0 | |`-- readdirp@2.1.0 | |   `--
>   set-immediate-shim@1.0.1 | +-- combine-lists@1.0.1 | +-- connect@3.6.2
>   | | +-- debug@2.6.7 | | +-- finalhandler@1.0.3 | | |`-- debug@2.6.7 |
>   | +-- parseurl@1.3.1 | | `-- utils-merge@1.0.0 | +-- di@0.0.1 | +--
>   dom-serialize@2.2.1 | | +-- custom-event@1.0.1 | | +-- ent@2.2.0 | |
>   +-- extend@3.0.1 | |`-- void-elements@2.0.1 | +-- expand-braces@0.1.2 | | +-- array-slice@0.2.3 | | +-- array-unique@0.2.1 | | `--
>   braces@0.1.5 | |`-- expand-range@0.1.1 | |     +-- is-number@0.1.1
>   | |     `-- repeat-string@0.2.2 | +-- graceful-fs@4.1.11 | +--
>   http-proxy@1.16.2 | | +-- eventemitter3@1.2.0 | |`--
>   requires-port@1.0.0 | +-- lodash@3.10.1 | +-- log4js@0.6.38 | | +--
>   readable-stream@1.0.34 | | | +-- core-util-is@1.0.2 | | | +--
>   isarray@0.0.1 | | | `-- string_decoder@0.10.31 | |`-- semver@4.3.6 |
>   +-- mime@1.3.6 | +-- optimist@0.6.1 | | +-- minimist@0.0.10 | | `-- wordwrap@0.0.3 | +-- qjobs@1.1.5 | +-- socket.io@1.4.7 | | +--
>   debug@2.2.0 | | |`-- ms@0.7.1 | | +-- engine.io@1.6.10 | | | +--
>   accepts@1.1.4 | | | | +-- mime-types@2.0.14 | | | | | `--
>   mime-db@1.12.0 | | | |`-- negotiator@0.4.9 | | | +-- base64id@0.1.0 |
>   | | +-- debug@2.2.0 | | | | `-- ms@0.7.1 | | | +--
>   engine.io-parser@1.2.4 | | | | +-- after@0.8.1 | | | | +--
>   arraybuffer.slice@0.0.6 | | | | +-- base64-arraybuffer@0.1.2 | | | |
>   +-- blob@0.0.4 | | | | +-- has-binary@0.1.6 | | | | |`-- isarray@0.0.1 | | | | `-- utf8@2.1.0 | | |`-- ws@1.0.1 | | |   +--
>   options@0.0.6 | | |   `-- ultron@1.0.2 | | +-- has-binary@0.1.7 | | |`
>   -- isarray@0.0.1 | | +-- socket.io-adapter@0.4.0 | | | +--
>   debug@2.2.0 | | | | `-- ms@0.7.1 | | |`-- socket.io-parser@2.2.2 | |
>   |   +-- debug@0.7.4 | | |   +-- isarray@0.0.1 | | |   `-- json3@3.2.6
>   | | +-- socket.io-client@1.4.6 | | | +-- backo2@1.0.2 | | | +--
>   component-bind@1.0.0 | | | +-- component-emitter@1.2.0 | | | +--
>   debug@2.2.0 | | | |`-- ms@0.7.1 | | | +-- engine.io-client@1.6.9 | |
>   | | +-- component-inherit@0.0.3 | | | | +-- debug@2.2.0 | | | | | `--
>   ms@0.7.1 | | | | +-- has-cors@1.1.0 | | | | +-- parsejson@0.0.1 | | |
>   | +-- parseqs@0.0.2 | | | | +-- xmlhttprequest-ssl@1.5.1 | | | |`--
>   yeast@0.1.2 | | | +-- indexof@0.0.1 | | | +-- object-component@0.0.3 |
>   | | +-- parseuri@0.0.4 | | | | `-- better-assert@1.0.2 | | | |`--
>   callsite@1.0.0 | | | `-- to-array@0.1.4 | |`-- socket.io-parser@2.2.6
>   | |   +-- benchmark@1.0.0 | |   +-- component-emitter@1.1.2 | |   +--
>   debug@2.2.0 | |   | `-- ms@0.7.1 | |`-- isarray@0.0.1 | +--
>   tmp@0.0.28 | `-- useragent@2.1.13 |   +-- lru-cache@2.2.4 |`--
>   tmp@0.0.31
>   webdriver@2.53.42 | +-- blocking-proxy@0.0.5 | +--
>   jasmine@2.6.0 | | +-- exit@0.1.2 | | `-- jasmine-core@2.6.3 | +--
>   jasminewd2@2.1.0 | +-- q@1.4.1 | +-- saucelabs@1.3.0 | |`--
>   https-proxy-agent@1.0.0 | |   `-- agent-base@2.1.1 | +--
>   selenium-webdriver@3.0.1 | |`-- tmp@0.0.30 | +--
>   source-map-support@0.4.15 | +-- webdriver-js-extender@1.0.0 | | `--
>   selenium-webdriver@2.53.3 | |   +-- adm-zip@0.4.4 | |   +-- tmp@0.0.24
>   | |`-- xml2js@0.4.4 | |     `-- sax@0.6.1 |`--
>   webdriver-manager@12.0.6 |   +-- adm-zip@0.4.7 |   +-- del@2.2.2 |   |
>   +-- globby@5.0.0 |   | | `-- array-union@1.0.2 |   | +-- is-path-cwd@1.0.0 |   | +-- is-path-in-cwd@1.0.0 |   | |`--
>   is-path-inside@1.0.0 |   | |   `-- path-is-inside@1.0.2 |   |`--
>   pify@2.3.0 |   +-- ini@1.3.4 |   +-- semver@5.3.0 |   `--
>   xml2js@0.4.17 |     +-- sax@1.2.2 |`-- xmlbuilder@4.2.1
>   +-- rxjs@5.4.1 | `-- symbol-observable@1.0.4
>   +-- ts-helpers@1.1.2
>   +-- ts-node@1.2.1 | +-- arrify@1.0.1 | +-- diff@2.2.3 | +-- make-error@1.3.0 | +-- mkdirp@0.5.1 | |`-- minimist@0.0.8 | +--
>   pinkie@2.0.4 | +-- tsconfig@5.0.3 | | +-- any-promise@1.3.0 | | +--
>   parse-json@2.2.0 | | | `-- error-ex@1.3.1 | | |`--
>   is-arrayish@0.2.1 | | +-- strip-bom@2.0.0 | | | `-- is-utf8@0.2.1 | |`
>   -- strip-json-comments@2.0.1 | `-- xtend@4.0.1
>   +-- tslint@4.5.1 | +-- babel-code-frame@6.22.0 | | +-- esutils@2.0.2 | |`-- js-tokens@3.0.1 | +-- findup-sync@0.3.0 | | `-- glob@5.0.15 |
>   +-- tsutils@1.9.1 |`-- update-notifier@2.2.0 |   +-- boxen@1.1.0 |   | +-- ansi-align@2.0.0 |   | +-- camelcase@4.1.0 |   | +--
>   cli-boxes@1.0.0 |   | +-- string-width@2.0.0 |   | | `--
>   is-fullwidth-code-point@2.0.0 |   | +-- term-size@0.1.1 |   | |`--
>   execa@0.4.0 |   | |   +-- cross-spawn-async@2.2.5 |   | |   +--
>   is-stream@1.1.0 |   | |   +-- npm-run-path@1.0.0 |   | |   +--
>   path-key@1.0.0 |   | |   `-- strip-eof@1.0.0 |   |`--
>   widest-line@1.0.0 |   +-- configstore@3.1.0 |   | +-- dot-prop@4.1.1 |
>   | | `-- is-obj@1.0.1 |   | +-- make-dir@1.0.0 |   | +--
>   unique-string@1.0.0 |   | |`-- crypto-random-string@1.0.0 |   | `--
>   write-file-atomic@2.1.0 |   |   +-- imurmurhash@0.1.4 |   |`--
>   slide@1.1.6 |   +-- import-lazy@2.1.0 |   +-- is-npm@1.0.0 |   +--
>   latest-version@3.1.0 |   | `-- package-json@4.0.1 |   |   +--
>   got@6.7.1 |   |   | +-- create-error-class@3.0.2 |   |   | |`--
>   capture-stack-trace@1.0.0 |   |   | +-- duplexer3@0.1.4 |   |   | +--
>   get-stream@3.0.0 |   |   | +-- is-redirect@1.0.0 |   |   | +--
>   is-retry-allowed@1.1.0 |   |   | +-- lowercase-keys@1.0.0 |   |   |
>   +-- timed-out@4.0.1 |   |   | +-- unzip-response@2.0.1 |   |   | `-- url-parse-lax@1.0.0 |   |   +-- registry-auth-token@3.3.1 |   |   +--
>   registry-url@3.1.0 |   |`-- semver@5.3.0 |   +-- semver-diff@2.1.0
>   |   | `-- semver@5.0.3 |`-- xdg-basedir@3.0.0
>   +-- typescript@2.0.10
>   +-- typings@2.1.0 | +-- archy@1.0.0 | +-- cli-truncate@0.2.1 | | +-- slice-ansi@0.0.4 | | `-- string-width@1.0.2 | |   +--
>
> exit-hook@1.1.1 | |     `-- onetime@1.1.0 | +-- promise-finally@3.0.0
>   | +-- typings-core@2.3.3 | | +-- array-uniq@1.0.3 | | +--
>   detect-indent@5.0.0 | | +-- invariant@2.2.2 | | |`--
>   loose-envify@1.3.1 | | +-- is-absolute@0.2.6 | | | +--
>   is-relative@0.2.1 | | | | `-- is-unc-path@0.1.2 | | | |`--
>   unc-path-regex@0.1.2 | | | `-- is-windows@0.2.0 | | +--
>   jspm-config@0.3.4 | | +-- lockfile@1.0.3 | | +--
>   make-error-cause@1.2.2 | | +-- object.pick@1.2.0 | | |`--
>   isobject@2.1.0 | | +-- popsicle@9.1.0 | | | +-- concat-stream@1.6.0 |
>   | | | `-- typedarray@0.0.6 | | |`-- form-data@2.2.0 | | +--
>   popsicle-proxy-agent@3.0.0 | | | `-- http-proxy-agent@1.0.0 | | +--
>   popsicle-retry@3.2.1 | | +-- popsicle-rewrite@1.0.0 | | +--
>   popsicle-status@2.0.1 | | +-- rc@1.2.1 | | |`-- deep-extend@0.4.2 | |
>   +-- sort-keys@1.1.2 | | | `-- is-plain-obj@1.1.0 | | +-- string-template@1.0.0 | | +-- strip-bom@3.0.0 | | +-- thenify@3.3.0 |
>   | +-- throat@3.2.0 | | +-- touch@1.0.0 | | |`-- nopt@1.0.10 | | `--
>   zip-object@0.1.0 | +-- update-notifier@1.0.3 | | +-- boxen@0.6.0 | | |
>   +-- ansi-align@1.1.0 | | | +-- camelcase@2.1.1 | | | +-- filled-array@1.1.0 | | |`-- repeating@2.0.1 | | |   `--
>   is-finite@1.0.2 | | +-- configstore@2.1.0 | | | +-- dot-prop@3.0.0 | |
>   |`-- write-file-atomic@1.3.4 | | +-- latest-version@2.0.0 | | | `--
>   package-json@2.4.0 | | |   +-- got@5.7.1 | | |   | +-- duplexer2@0.1.4
>   | | |   | +-- node-status-codes@1.0.0 | | |   | +--
>   read-all-stream@3.1.0 | | |   | +-- timed-out@3.1.3 | | |   |`--
>   unzip-response@1.0.2 | | |   `-- semver@5.3.0 | | +-- lazy-req@1.1.0 |
>   |`-- xdg-basedir@2.0.0 | `-- wordwrap@1.0.0`-- zone.js@0.7.8
>
> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0
>   (node_modules\ch
>   okidar\node_modules\fsevents): npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL
>   DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@
>   1.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"}
>   ) npm WARN @angular/forms@4.2.2 requires a peer of
>   @angular/platform-browser@4.2.2
>   but none was installed. npm WARN @angular/core@4.2.2 requires a peer
>   of zone.js@^0.8.4 but none was inst
>   alled.

Here is my `app.component.ts`:

```
import { Component, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Modal, Overlay } from 'angular2-modal';
import { Utilisateur } from './shared/utilisateur';
import { PanierService } from './panier.service';
import { ParentService } from './parent.service';
import { ConfirmDialogModule, ConfirmationService } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { PanierNumber } from './shared/panier';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [PanierNumber]

})
export class AppComponent {
  userRole: string;
  displayLogin: boolean = false;
  displayRegister: boolean = false;
  open: any = -1;
  year: number;
  nrPanier: number;

  constructor( private utilisateur: Utilisateur, private router: Router, private modal: Modal, overlay: Overlay, viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
               private confirmationService: ConfirmationService, private panierService: PanierService, private parentService: ParentService, private panierNumber: PanierNumber) {
                this.nrPanier = 0;
                this.year = new Date().getFullYear();
                overlay.defaultViewContainer = viewContainer;
                this.utilisateur.mySubject.subscribe(
                    value => {
                        this.userRole = value;
                        this.displayLogin = false;
                    }
                  );
                  if(localStorage.getItem("currentUserPDF")){
                    this.utilisateur.role = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentUserPDF")).role;
                    if(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentUserPDF")).role == "PARENT"){
                      this.parentService.getParent(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentUserPDF")).id).subscribe(r => {
                          r.enfants.forEach(e => {
                              this.panierService.getPanier(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentUserPDF")).id, e.id).subscribe(r => {
                                  r.forEach(h => {
                                      this.nrPanier++;
                                  });
                                  this.panierNumber.setNumber(this.nrPanier);
                              });
                          });

                      });

                      this.panierNumber.numberPanier$.subscribe(nr => {
                        this.nrPanier = nr;
                      });
                    }
                  }

  }
  checkToken() {
      if(localStorage.getItem("accessToken")) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
  }
  confirmLogout() {
      this.confirmationService.confirm({
          message: 'Êtes-vous sûr de vouloir vous déconnecter ?',
          header: "Déconnexion",
          accept: () => {
             localStorage.removeItem('currentUserPDF');
             localStorage.removeItem("accessToken");
             this.router.navigate(['']);
            }
      });
  }
  openLoginModal() {
        this.displayLogin = true;
  }
  openRegisterModal() {
        this.displayRegister = true;
  }
  toggle() {
    this.open = this.open*-1;
  }
  isOpen() {
    if(this.open>0) {
      return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
  }
  goToPanier(){
    this.router.navigate(['/panier']);
  }
}
```

Here is my `package.json` :

```
{
  "name": "place-des-familles-front",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "^3.4.0",
    "@types/fullcalendar": "^2.7.42",
    "@types/jquery": "^2.0.44",
    "angular2-google-maps": "^0.17.0",
    "angular2-modal": "^2.0.3",
    "ap-angular2-fullcalendar": "^1.2.8",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "fullcalendar": "^3.4.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "ng2-google-recaptcha": "1.1.0",
    "primeng": "^2.0.6",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "typings": "2.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0-beta.31",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/jquery": "^2.0.43",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "^4.3.0",
    "typescript": "~2.0.0"
  }
}
```

Here is my `app.component.html` :

```
<nav>
    <a routerLink=''><img src="./assets/img/logo.png" height="66"></a>
    <button class="collapse" type="button" pButton (click)="toggle()" icon="fa-bars"></button>
    <div class="nav1">
        <div *ngIf="!checkToken()">
            <div class="navbar-div" ><a class="navbar-a" routerLink='./rechercher_creche'> recherche </a></div>
            <div class="navbar-div" ><a class="navbar-a" routerLink='./register'> inscription </a></div>
            <div class="navbar-div"><a class="navbar-a" (click)="openLoginModal()"> connexion </a></div>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="checkToken()">
            <div class="navbar-div" *ngIf="checkToken() && utilisateur.role.toLowerCase()=='parent'" (click)="goToPanier()" style="cursor: pointer;">
                <img src="./assets/img/panier.jpg" style="width: 20px; float: right"/>
                <span style="float: right; color: #428bca;">{{nrPanier}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-div" ><a class="navbar-a" (click)="confirmLogout()"> déconnexion </a></div>
            <div class="navbar-div" *ngIf="utilisateur.role.toLowerCase()=='parent'"><a class="navbar-a" routerLink='compte_famille'> mon compte </a></div>
            <div class="navbar-div" *ngIf="utilisateur.role.toLowerCase()!='parent'"><a class="navbar-a" routerLink='etablissement'> professionnels </a></div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="nav2" [ngClass]="{'in': isOpen()}">
        <div *ngIf="!checkToken()">
            <div class="navbar-div"  (click)="toggle()"><a class="navbar-a" (click)="openLoginModal()"> connexion </a></div>
            <div class="navbar-div"  (click)="toggle()"><a class="navbar-a" routerLink='./register'> inscription </a></div>
            <div class="navbar-div"  (click)="toggle()"><a class="navbar-a" routerLink='./rechercher_creche'> recherche </a></div>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="checkToken()"> 
            <div class="navbar-div"  (click)="toggle()"><a class="navbar-a" routerLink='compte_famille'> mon compte </a></div>
            <div class="navbar-div"  (click)="toggle()"><a class="navbar-a" (click)="confirmLogout()"> déconnexion </a></div>
            <div class="navbar-div" *ngIf="checkToken() && utilisateur.role.toLowerCase()=='parent'" (click)="goToPanier()" style="cursor: pointer;">
                <img src="./assets/img/panier.jpg" style="width: 20px; float: right"/>
                <span style="float: right; color: #428bca;">{{nrPanier}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>


<p-dialog header="Connexion" [(visible)]="displayLogin" [dismissableMask]="true" modal="modal" responsive="true" styleClass="crecheTab">
    <login></login>
</p-dialog>

<p-confirmDialog icon="fa fa-question-circle" #cd responsive="true">
    <p-footer>
        <button type="button" pButton icon="fa-close"label="Non" (click)="cd.reject()" style="background-color:#3887C9;font-family: raleway;"></button>
        <button type="button" pButton icon="fa-check" label="Oui" (click)="cd.accept()" style="background-color:#3887C9;font-family: raleway;"></button>
    </p-footer>
</p-confirmDialog>

<footer>
    <div class="foot1 ui-g">
        <table class='footer-table ui-g-10 ui-md-4 ui-lg-3'>
            <tr>
                <th class='footer-th'> C'EST PRATIQUE </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <ul class='footer-ul'>
                        <li> <a class='footer-a' routerLink=''> Foire aux questions </a></li>
                        <li> <a class='footer-a' routerLink=''> Professionnels petite enfance </a></li>
                        <li> <a class='footer-a' routerLink=''> Application mobile </a></li>
                    </ul> 
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table class='footer-table ui-g-10 ui-md-4 ui-lg-3'>
            <tr>
                <th class='footer-th'> C'EST NOUS ! </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <ul class='footer-ul'>
                        <li> <a class='footer-a' routerLink='./qui_sommes_nous'> Qui nous sommes ? </a></li>
                        <li> <a class='footer-a' routerLink=''> Nos partenaires </a></li>
                        <li> <a class='footer-a' routerLink=''> Nous recrutons </a></li>
                    </ul> 
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table class='footer-table ui-g-10 ui-md-4 ui-lg-3'>
            <tr>
                <th class='footer-th'> C'EST LÉGAL </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <ul class='footer-ul'>
                        <li> <a class='footer-a' routerLink='./cgu'> Conditions générales d'utilisation </a></li>
                        <li> <a class='footer-a' routerLink='./mentions_legales'> Notice légale </a></li>
                    </ul> 
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div class="foot2">
        Place des Familles - {{year}} <i class="fa fa-registered" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
</footer>
```

EDIT : 
In my class 'utilisateur', I define a default value for the role so it should not be undefined :

```
@Injectable()
export class Utilisateur {
    public id: number;
    public prenom: string;
    public nom: string;
    public login: string;
    public role: string = 'guest';
    public codePostal: string;
    public ville: string;
    public accessToken: string;
    public civilite: string;
    public mySubject: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>(this.role);
    public changeRole(): void {
        this.mySubject.next(this.role);
    }
}
```

Ask me for any more information.

Comment: Can you include your html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your error indicates, `utilisateur.role` is not defined by the time you execute your `*ngIf` hence `utilisateur.role.lowerCase()` is throwing an error. You can do a workaround like this:

```
*ngIf="utilisateur.role && utilisateur.role.toLowerCase()=='parent'">
```

this will first check for `utilisateur.role` and if it is `undefined`, it will be evaluated to false.

Comment: How can I define it before the `*ngIf` is executed ?

Comment: But in my class Utilisateur, I define a default value for role : 
`@Injectable()
    export class Utilisateur {
    public id: number;
    public prenom: string;
    public nom: string;
    public login: string;
    public role: string = 'guest';
    public codePostal: string;
    public ville: string;
    public accessToken: string;
    public civilite: string;


    public mySubject: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>(this.role);
    public changeRole(): void {
        this.mySubject.next(this.role);
    }
}`

Comment: @anais1477 It's hard to read it from here. Can you add it to your question? And you can define it inside the constructor before your subscribe function. And didn't this answer work? You are practically checking for null values, IMO this way is always more secure.

Comment: So I had this line at the top of my constructor method : `this.utilisateur.role = 'guest';`
It doesn't change anything :/

Comment: @anais1477 hmm strange, maybe the html is executed before the dependency injection. Does my answer work?

Comment: Yes it works ! But I do not understand why my code worked before and not now :/ 
Thx !!